# MongoDB autherization is ignored when we use mongo object

Tags: java, mongodb

I tried to authenticate mongodb using mongo object provided by java driver. The problem here is what ever the authentication details is been passed is ignored and still I could able to connect to mongodb without any exceptions. Please help me in finding the right approach.

The code I tried with is

```
DBAddress leftServerAddress = new DBAddress("209.235.220.243:27017/"+dbName);    
DBAddress rightServerAddress = new DBAddress("209.235.220.242:26017/"+dbName);
Mongo mongo = new Mongo(leftServerAddress,rightServerAddress);    
DB db;    
db.authenticate("althaf", "althaf".toCharArray());
```

Switching between servers is happenning properly where as the authentication alone is ignored. Please suggest me the proper approach

Comment: Can you explain and give an example of how the authorization is being ignored? Can you tell us what privileges your user has and give an example of those privileges not being respected? What version of the Java driver are you using? You should be connecting with `MongoClient` instead of `Mongo`.

Comment: Thanks you so much!! I used MongoClinet and it is working fine.

Comment: What I tried with basically is Mongo instead of MongoClient. Authorization setup has to be done at mongodb level.